# reading and displaying data from a Firebase database

Tags: angular, firebase

I am trying to retreive data from a firebase database and store the data in a courses array i've defined in my class.

So far I've got :

```
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-page',
  templateUrl: './home-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home-page.component.css']
})
export class HomePageComponent implements OnInit {


  courses:any[];


  constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth,private router:Router,private db:AngularFireDatabase) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    if(this.afAuth.auth.currentUser){


        var ref = this.db.database.ref('/courses');

        ref.on("value", this.gotData, function (error) {
          console.log("Error: " + error.code);
        });


    }else{      
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    }

  }

  gotData(data){
    var x = data.val();
    console.log(x);
    this.courses = x; // >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>  ISSUE HERE
  }


}
```

However I am getting this error saying :

> FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. TypeError:
>   Cannot set property 'courses' of null

and

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'courses' of null

I am able to successfully console log the data.. but I want to store this data.. how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells you that `this` is null. To ensure that it is preserved, define `gotData` as an arrow function:

```
gotData = (data) => {
   this.courses = data.val();
}
```

Comment: I did the below :

ref.on("value", (data)=>{let x = data.val();this.courses=x;console.log(this.courses);}, function (error) { 
console.log("Error oops: " + error.code); 
});

and it worked now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the courses

```
 courses:any[] = [];
```

Comment: i guess the problem lies here  ref.on("value", this.gotData, function (error) {
          console.log("Error: " + error.code);
        });

Comment: this.gotdata is a function.

Comment: is it not ok to pass in a function there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162202/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-psj01).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41668789/cannot-set-property-variable-of-null-on-firebase